# Resumindo aniversariantes por mês (SQL)

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, stored-procedures

Estou tentando contar a quantidade de clientes aniversariantes por mês no meu banco de dados, porém eu só consigo fazer ele exibir os meses que possuem aniversariantes, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu preciso que ele mostre os meses que não possuem aniversariantes tendo na contagem 0, mas não consigo fazer.

Código que eu fiz até aqui

```
 --Aniversariante por Mês (quantidade e cada mês)
go
create procedure Aniversariante_Count
as
    begin

        select case MONTH(C.DATANASCIMENTO)
        when 1  then 'Janeiro'
        when 2  then 'Fevereiro'
        when 3  then 'Março'
        when 4  then 'Abril'
        when 5  then 'Maio'
        when 6  then 'Junho'
        when 7  then 'Julho'
        when 8  then 'Agosto'
        when 9  then 'Setembro'
        when 10 then 'Outubro'
        when 11 then 'Novembro'
        when 12 then 'Dezembro'
        end as MES,  count(month(C.DATANASCIMENTO)) as Aniversariantes
        from CLIENTES C 
        group by month(C.DATANASCIMENTO) 
    
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Bea!

Para trazer os campos em um count considerando os nulos e dando o valor zerado caso não tenho nada existe a função COALESCE, pois acredito que vai conseguir te ajudar.

> Obs. O COALSESCE não funcionou pois o problema não é que os meses tem
> valores nulos, não existe o Mês dentro da base e assim ele não
> consegue trazer mesmo, nesse caso o melhor é criar uma estrutura e
> assim inserir os valores dentro, segue como fazer:

**Aqui vamos criar a tabela com campos vazios para fazer o left join na sua tabela e assim mesmo que não tiver valores vai funcionar:**

```
CREATE TABLE meses_novo (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, meses TEXT);

INSERT INTO meses VALUES (1, "Janeiro");
INSERT INTO meses VALUES (2, "Fevereiro");
INSERT INTO meses VALUES (3, "Março");
INSERT INTO meses VALUES (4, "Abril");
INSERT INTO meses VALUES (5, "Maio");
INSERT INTO meses VALUES (6, "Junho");
INSERT INTO meses VALUES (7, "Julho");
INSERT INTO meses VALUES (8, "Agosto");
INSERT INTO meses VALUES (9, "Setembro");
INSERT INTO meses VALUES (10, "Outubro");
INSERT INTO meses VALUES (11, "Novembro");
INSERT INTO meses VALUES (12, "Dezembro");

SELECT * FROM meses_novo;
```

**Vou manter a QUERY antiga para você não se confundir:**

```
--Aniversariante por Mês (quantidade e cada mês)
go
create procedure Aniversariante_Count
as
    begin

        select case MONTH(C.DATANASCIMENTO)
        when 1  then 'Janeiro'
        when 2  then 'Fevereiro'
        when 3  then 'Março'
        when 4  then 'Abril'
        when 5  then 'Maio'
        when 6  then 'Junho'
        when 7  then 'Julho'
        when 8  then 'Agosto'
        when 9  then 'Setembro'
        when 10 then 'Outubro'
        when 11 then 'Novembro'
        when 12 then 'Dezembro'
        end as MES, count(month(C.DATANASCIMENTO)) as Aniversariantes
        from CLIENTES C 
        group by month(C.DATANASCIMENTO) 
    
    end
```

**Ultima QUERY fazendo o Join entre as 2 tabelas criadas:**

```
 CREATE TABLE uniao as select
  a.*,
  b.Aniversariantes
 
  FROM a.meses_novo a left join Aniversariante_Count b on
  a.meses = b.MES
  END
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, porém testei aqui e deu na mesma, ainda não aparece os meses sem aniversariantes

Comment: Bea se não deu certo é porque como você esta criando os meses utilizando o "CASE WHEN" não irá aparecer mesmo com o COALENSCE, nesse caso a melhor forma seria utilizando um left join em cima de uma base dos meses.

Comment: Tentei aqui e funcionou, muito obrigada